# Wordpress Uploader Editor shows broken image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have the latest wordpress version installed.  When I upload an image in the control panel for a post, I then go to edit it (crop an image for the thumbnail the way I want or rotate or do any kind of editing) and instead it shows a broken image.

The actual images are uploaded, I just can't seem to use the wordpress image editor.

Any ideas why or how to fix?  See image below for more detail

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions on the file as it sits on the server. Try loading the image URL into a browser and see what error displays. Sometimes I can duplicate the image and reupload and it works. Just some things to try.

Comment: If I right click, open image in new window on the broken image in the screenshot above it will try opening a URL like this... `http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=29db12886f&postid=34&rand=94296` and will show a broken image on that page as well.  So far everything I have tried has not helped and I have tried uploading several images and all of them have the same result.  I change the images full permissions 666 and then 777 but still the same result

Comment: I have made some progress in finding the problem, In my functions file I have about 10 other files that I include into my functions files that do all kinds of stuff, 1 by 1 I disabled each file and eventually I got it working as long as my file I call `cd-widgets.php` is not included, so my problem is somewhere in my widget code.  Shouldn't take long to fix now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and find that in one of my plugins I had a file that started with a blank line before

Problem:

```
1. 
2. <?php
3. /**
4.  * Comment
```

Solution:

```
1. <?php
2. /**
3.  * Comment
```